# How to export a cleaned dataframe to csv?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am attempting to export a cleaned dataframe to a csv file for it to be imported into a new jupyter notebook for ML purposes.

I ran the following code:
df_train.to_csv('../datasets/new_train.csv')

However, the output file, when opened, contains the same dataset as the input file (before cleaning).

Comment: You'll need to show more code. Perhaps you didn't assign the scrubbed dataframe to a variable or you needed the `inplace=True` parameter. Be default, many pandas functions make a copy of the df and return that.

Comment: Hi, I did put inplace=True in my final step when I drop rows within the dataframe that contains null values in a particular column:

df_train.dropna(subset=['Mall_Nearest_Distance'], inplace=True)

Comment: Asssuming you have multiple steps, you could save temporary csvs along the way to see if the data is being removed as you want. Or write temporary tests to make sure the bad data is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide a minimal repeatable example, based on comments it is not clear on the mistake. Here is the sample code to prove it works

```py
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['jerry', ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
print(df)
df.dropna(subset=['Age'], inplace=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv('names.csv')
```

Output of above code

```
    Name   Age
0    tom  10.0
1   nick  15.0
2   juli  14.0
3  jerry   NaN
   Name   Age
0   tom  10.0
1  nick  15.0
2  juli  14.0
```

Output of `cat names.csv`

```
,Name,Age
0,tom,10.0
1,nick,15.0
2,juli,14.0
```